# Google Apps Scripts to automatically convert to GBP

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the code below that scans through a cost column (E) and extracts the currency from it before mapping it to its corresponding 3 digit currency code and printing in column AD.

So let's say E3= $9.99, this script will extract the "$", map it to "USD" then print this in cell AD3.

How can I amend this code to auto-convert the $9.99 to GBP (so £8)? Ideally without needing to print the 3 digit currency code to column AD but rather just printing the final GBP value to some column (with £ formatting).

It doesn't need to return super time critical data from some company's API so I am thinking it's best using GOOGLEFINANCE within the script. I have used this formula before in Google Sheets but never within a script. You may ask why I am not using =GOOGLEFINANCE as a formula? I would like to design my spreadsheet in a way that after adding cost, it is converted to GBP. If I use GOOGLEFINANCE as a formula then it would always recalculate based on new data (unless I hardcoded a date but this isn't possible because of the structure of my file and the fact date will always change).

I basically need something like the below inside the script where CURRENCYCODE is dynamic and dependent on the cell being pulled from.

=GoogleFinance("CURRENCYCODEgbp","price",, today())

I am also open to other suggestions on how to convert to GBP (ultimately the goal here) - as long as they don't involve a paid service.

```
function extractCurrencyCode() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("E3:E" + sheet.getLastRow());
  var values = range.getDisplayValues();
  var currencyCodes = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var cost = values[i][0];
    var currencyCode = cost.replace(/\d|\.|\s/g, "");
    var currencySymbolToCode = {
      "$": "USD",
      "€": "EUR",
      "£": "GBP",
    };
    currencyCodes.push([currencySymbolToCode[currencyCode] || ""]); // Retrieve code from mapping, or use an empty string if not found
  }

  var currencyCodeRange = sheet.getRange("AD3:AD" + (currencyCodes.length + 2));
  currencyCodeRange.setValues(currencyCodes);
}
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to convert USD to GBP using `GOOGLEFINANCE` and Google Apps Script.
- Your source values are put into the cells "E3:E".
- You want to achieve this by modifying your showing script.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function extractCurrencyCode() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("E3:E" + sheet.getLastRow());
  var values = range.getDisplayValues();
  var values2 = range.getValues();
  var currencyCodes = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var cost = values[i][0];
    var currencyCode = cost.replace(/\d|\.|,|\s/g, "");
    var currencySymbolToCode = {
      "$": [`=GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:USDGBP") * ${values2[i][0]}`, "USD to GBP"], // or [`=GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:USDGBP") * E${i + 3}`, "USD to GBP"]
      "€": [`=GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:EURGBP") * ${values2[i][0]}`, "EUR to GBP"], // or [`=GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:EURGBP") * E${i + 3}`, "EUR to GBP"]
      "£": [values2[i][0], "GBP"],
    };
    currencyCodes.push(currencySymbolToCode[currencyCode] || Array(2).fill(""));
  }
  var currencyCodeRange = sheet.getRange("F3:G" + (currencyCodes.length + 2));
  currencyCodeRange.setValues(currencyCodes);
}
```

- When this script is run, the values are retrieved from cells "E3:E". And, the values are converted to GBP using `GOOGLEFINANCE`. And, those values are put into columns F and G. Please modify the output columns to your actual situation.
- This is a simple modification. Please modify this to your actual situation.

Answer (score 1):

### Alternate Solution:

I happened to find a github library from [bkper](https://github.com/bkper/exchange-app) that was published as a google apps script library that converts one currency to another currency .

Alternately, you can this libray, [ExchangeApp](https://github.com/bkper/exchange-app#exchangeapp) aside from `Google Finance`.

You just need to setup and install this library inside your Apps Script.

> To add it to your script, do the following in the Apps Script code
> editor:
>
> 1. Click on the menu item "Resources > Libraries..."
> 2. In the "Add a Library" text box, enter the Script ID    "12pPyeoZrmRDHjGnm4brpl-uIr424_bjAtFMjedtr5aJc_Pt7vKg3IGwy" and click
>    the "Select" button.
> 3. Choose a version in the dropdown box (usually best to pick the latest version).
> 4. Click the "Save" button.

### Modified script:

Based from your existing script you can use this as a based point for your desired outcome.

```
function extractCurrencyCode() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
  var display = range.getDisplayValues();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var currencyCodes = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < display.length; i++) {
    var cost = display[i][0];
    var currencyCode = cost.replace(/\d|\.|\s/g, "");
    var currencySymbolToCode = {
      "$": [ExchangeApp.exchange(values[i][0]).from('USD').to('GBP').convert()], //convert values to GBP using ExchangeApp library
      "€": [ExchangeApp.exchange(values[i][0]).from('EUR').to('GBP').convert()], //convert values to GBP using ExchangeApp library
      "£": [values[i][0]],
    };
    currencyCodes.push(currencySymbolToCode[currencyCode]); // Retrieve code from mapping, or use an empty string if not found
  }
  var currencyCodeRange = sheet.getRange("B2:B" + (currencyCodes.length + 1));
  currencyCodeRange.setValues(currencyCodes);
}
```

Please note that range and column may differ from your sheet.

### Output:

[image]

**Disclaimer**: I am not affiliated with github nor with the one who develops the github library.

### References:

https://github.com/bkper/exchange-app